# Paramiko sending text to psuedo shell

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Testing sending commands to IoT devices that drops the user into a python script instead of a bash shell.

i.e. in **/etc/passwd**  - *admin:x:1000:0:admin:/home/admin:/home/admin/IoT.py*

So cant use the normal bash exec_commands to talk to the python script. Basically once it connects it needs the send a command string and receive the output. Below the script reads IP addresses from a text file, whats the correct way to send and receive commands

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
import sys

def LogonSSH(ipAddress) :

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    for line in open(ipAddress, "r").readlines() :

        ipAddr = line.strip()
        username='admin'
        password='admin'

        try :
            print "[+] Trying %s with username: %s password: %s " % (ipAddr, username, password)
            ssh.connect(ipAddr, username=username, password=password)

        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
            print "[x] %s  - could not log in" % (ipAddr)
            continue

                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('help')
                stdin.flush()
            stdin.write('help\n')
                out = stdout.read()
                stdin.flush()
                print out
                ssh.close()
                break

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    LogonSSH(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Below changes might help you. Just make send and recv, recv only takes the last commands output, but you need to consider:

- Put some sleep after sending command (just trial and error)
- Some tricks on output data, because it has invisible string parts such as (`<pre>..</pre>`)
- Some output data might be too big to handle > 65100 bytes of recv, just check Paramiko Docs for recv method.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
import sys

def LogonSSH(ipAddress) :
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    for line in open(ipAddress, "r").readlines() :
        ipAddr = line.strip()
        username='admin'
        password='admin'

        try:
            print "[+] Trying %s with username: %s password: %s " % (ipAddr, username, password)
            ssh.connect(ipAddr, port=22, username=uname, password=pin, timeout=240,banner_timeout=250, auth_timeout=500)
            my_ssh_shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Some exception occured:" + str(ex))
            continue

        my_ssh_shell.send(bytes("help" + "\x0D", 'utf-8'))
        result_screen = my_ssh_shell.recv(65100).decode('ascii')
        print("Your SSH -help- command returns:" + str(result_screen))
        my_ssh_shell.close()
        break

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    LogonSSH(sys.argv[1])
```

Edit: Just change it to any exception for connection, and also some additional paramters on connection string.

Comment: yours gives the same output im getting: **Unknown command:  -c**

Comment: @illwill I just changed connection string and exception parts to be sure if you have valid connection. If you have a valid connection and your `help` command is correct this should give the result. One more thing, If you share the exact error message in your question it might help me better to understand issue with the lines on your code and also on paramiko code.

Comment: had to fix `my_ssh_shell.send(bytes("help" + "\x0D".encode('utf-8')))` for python2 but response i get now is



**Your SSH -help- command returns:Last login: Sat Apr 18 07:23:53 2020 from x.x.x.x**  it should at least have a few more lines from the motd,  might be getting cut off with newline?

Comment: That's comman problem, you should use recv part in a loop and your exit condition will be the prompt exits such as; "xx.xx.xx.xx#" or "some-text>" you should make your code to wait prompt and concate recv text into a string. I will replace code with this method in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get the MOTD, but send still not working

```
             my_ssh_shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
                my_ssh_shell.settimeout(2)
                while True :
                    data = my_ssh_shell.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
                    if len(data) < 1 :break
                    print(data)
                return
                  #### DOESNT SEND HERE OR GET RECEIVE RESULTS#########
              #      my_ssh_shell.send('help\n') 
              #      while True :
              #          data = my_ssh_shell.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
              #          if len(data) < 1 :break
              #          print(data)
              #      return  
                my_ssh_shell.close()
```